# $L^p(\mathbb R^n,\mu)$ and $L^p(\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\},\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. Some authors usually use the notation $L^p(\mathbb R^n,\mu)$, that means the set of all measurable functions $f:\mathbb R^b\to\mathbb C$ so that $\int\limits_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x)|^pd\mu<\infty$. The same definition for $L^p(\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\},\mu)$, the set contains all function $f:\mathbb R^b\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb C$ so that $\int\limits_{\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}}|f(x)|^pd\mu<\infty$.

Since $f$ is measurable thus it is no important that if we remove some point in the domain of function $f$. Is it right? Thus there is no difference between $L^p(\mathbb R^n,\mu)$ and $L^p(\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\},\mu)$. So why the authors still use the second notation? Or I get some misunderstanding?

As the same if we replace $d\mu$ by $\omega d\mu$, where $\omega$ is a non-negative, locally integrable function on $\mathbb R^n$. Do they equiv to each other?

Comment: What is $\mu$? If $\mu(\{0\})=0$ then there is no difference.

Comment: $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, as I wrote.

Comment: Do you have examples of uses of the second notation?

Answer (score 1):

If $\nu$ is a measure such that $\nu(\{0\})=0$, then the spaces $L^p(\mathbb R^n,\nu)$ and $L^p(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\},\nu)$ are naturally isometric, and thus can be identified.

Lacking any references, it seems impossible to tell why someone somewhere would use the second notation.